# Handling JDBC connection when v$session.osuser value is more than 30 chars

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I am installing a third party application and it set the value of v$session.osuser to the user name when connecting to oracle 12.1. Unfortunately the username of my linux account is 34 chars long and because of this installation is not able to complete.

I can't change the linux account username and also can't edit connection properties programmatically as I don't have access to the application source.

Below are my attempts so far (that didn't work):

1. Updated .bash_profile to trim the value of linux USER property to 29 chars
2. Added two command line argruments, -Doracle.jdbc.v$session.osuser={USER:0:29} and -Duser.name={USER:0:29}

Any other way options that would work?

Comment: Is upgrading to Oracle 12.2 an option?  That version allows up to 128 bytes.

Comment: I did upgrade it to 12.2. As you said osuser column takes 128 chars in this version, but I am still getting the format error on this column. Does it have any restriction on special characters inserted on that column? we are using @ and . in the username

Comment: I don't think the database typically restricts those characters.  I looked at `select distinct osuser from gv$session;` on 400 databases and found letters, numbers, "$", "/', ".", "@", and "_" in the names.  Can you add exactly what error message you're getting?

Comment: I found the issue. The ojdbc jar we are using is still validating for 30 chars even though oracle supports 128chars. We are currently using ojdbc8-12.2.0.1 jar. Do we have any other latest ojdbc jar for 12.2 version ?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
java -Doracle.jdbc.v\$session.osuser="my_user" ...
```

Comment: Very brief answer. Could you make it little more descriptive?

Comment: @Nikolay For instance: using this command-line /appli/java/java8/bin/java   -Doracle.jdbc.v\$session.osuser="santa_claus"  myjar.jar will make the Oracle sessions you create within your app appear as started by Osuser "santa_claus". In other words, v$session.osuser will read "santa_claus". You can also set those 3 columns: -Doracle.jdbc.v\$session.machine="whatever" -Doracle.jdbc.v\$session.program="My program" -Doracle.jdbc.v\$session.terminal="My term"

Comment: Starting with Oracle Database Release 18c, the JDBC driver supports a new file ojdbc.properties that makes it easier to pass connection properties to Java applications. In this file, you may use something like: oracle.jdbc.v$session.osuser=<my short username>

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and managed to fix it by setting the user.name value in the JVM. So, add:

```
-Duser.name=<shorter-name>
```

... as an option when starting the JVM.

Comment: I managed to fix this issue using export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.name=<shorter-name>

Comment: @KumarV That did it for me. This is the solution when using SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

for SQLDeveloper MacOS, I added this line

```
AddVMOption -Duser.name=danieloleary
```

into file `~/.sqldeveloper/21.4.2/product.conf`
then restarted the application.