# v$session.osuser error while testing a database connection in SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

> Status : Failure -Test failed: Connection property: format error:
> Property is 'v$session.osuser' and value is 'Family (Madhuri)'

This is the exact error I was getting whenever I try to connect to a new database in SQL DEVELOPER.

I don't exactly know what to do.

And I Tried to Install sql dev in another user And it worked fine so how can i make it work in my main acc/user

Comment: Might be able to resolve by setting a value for user name as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57143838/6568

Answer (score 1):

Your credentials are having special characters like `(` if yes remove them n then try. Usually, it shouldve shown you if thats the correct username or passwd you may be using it doesnt allow. But again maybe you are using a script to run try to remove special chars as its formatting error. Can refer below as well if that helps

[Handling JDBC connection when v$session.osuser value is more than 30 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336096/handling-jdbc-connection-when-vsession-osuser-value-is-more-than-30-chars)

Comment: The thing is "(madhuri) " used to be my username before but now i have changed it yet it is taking that old name. so is there any way to change that?

Comment: Try adding this `-Duser.name=<shorter-name>` refer the link which ive shared for more details

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes form you have parenthesis in your username.
Try located to SQLdeveloper directory that you installed SQL developer

```
\sqldeveloper\ide\bin\ide.conf
```

for example
C:\Program Files\sqldeveloper\ide\bin\ide.conf

edit **ide.conf** file by adding

```
AddVMOption  -Duser.name=<YourUsername>
```

`<YourUsername>` should not contain any parenthesis

save it and reopen SQL Developer, this should solve your problem.